# gRPC onComplete for bidistream

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

In all the gRPC bidistream examples that I have seen follow a pattern that when (inbound) requestObserver receives **onComplete** it invokes the **onComplete** method of the (outbound) responseObserver. However, this is not done for onError.

Wondering what happens if I don't invoke responseObserver.onComplete() does it lead to memory leak? Why we don't do it for onError?

```java
public StreamObserver<Point> recordRoute(final StreamObserver<RouteSummary> responseObserver) {
  return new StreamObserver<Point>() {

    @Override
    public void onNext(Point point) {
      // does something here
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
      logger.log(Level.WARNING, "recordRoute cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
      responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wondering what happens if I don't invoke responseObserver.onComplete() does it lead to memory leak?

An RPC is not complete/done until the response stream is also "completed" so yes there will be resource leak if you don't eventually call `responseObserver.onCompleted()`. In this particular example it just so happens that the response stream is terminated when the request stream is "complete" but there could be cases where the response stream is "completed" only after more processing is done or more data is sent on the response stream.

> Why we don't do it for onError?

onError() is a terminating error from the stream which means the call is terminated. onError() on the response stream is not needed and most probably won't  do anything.